# Setup an Access Point with Ubuntu Server on Raspberry Pi

Tags: networking, server, 18.04, raspberrypi, wireless-access-point

I would like to setup my Ubuntu Server to create a wifi network to which people can connect and open local webpages. The created wifi network **must not provide access to the internet** and should only allow the access to local webpages.

However, it is necessarry that the **ubuntu server**, which runs on a raspberry pi, **has access** to the internet.

### This graphical illustration clarifies my requirements:

```
                                 |
                 wifi            |           wired            wan
mobile-phone <~.~.~.~.~> (wlan0)RPi(eth0) <---------> router <---> INTERNET
            \             /      |     \             /
           (dhcp)   192.168.4.1  |    (dhcp)   192.168.50.1
```

I don't have the slightest idea how I could achieve this and would be incredbily thankful for any help/tutorial I get.

### My System Information / Hardware Specs:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic

ubuntu
    description: Computer
    product: Raspberry Pi 3 Model B Plus Rev 1.3
    serial: 000000006d462490
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smp cp15_barrier setend swp
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       physical id: 0
     *-cpu:0
          description: CPU
          product: cpu
          physical id: 0
          bus info: cpu@0
          size: 1400MHz
          capacity: 1400MHz
          capabilities: fp asimd evtstrm crc32 cpuid cpufreq
     *-cpu:1
          description: CPU
          product: cpu
          physical id: 1
          bus info: cpu@1
          size: 1400MHz
          capacity: 1400MHz
          capabilities: fp asimd evtstrm crc32 cpuid cpufreq
     *-cpu:2
          description: CPU
          product: cpu
          physical id: 2
          bus info: cpu@2
          size: 1400MHz
          capacity: 1400MHz
          capabilities: fp asimd evtstrm crc32 cpuid cpufreq
     *-cpu:3
          description: CPU
          product: cpu
          physical id: 3
          bus info: cpu@3
          size: 1400MHz
          capacity: 1400MHz
          capabilities: fp asimd evtstrm crc32 cpuid cpufreq
     *-memory
          description: System memory
          physical id: 4
          size: 912MiB
  *-usbhost
       product: DWC OTG Controller
       vendor: Linux 4.15.0-1041-raspi2 dwc_otg_hcd
       physical id: 1
       bus info: usb@1
       logical name: usb1
       version: 4.15
       capabilities: usb-2.00
       configuration: driver=hub slots=1 speed=480Mbit/s
     *-usb
          description: USB hub
          product: USB 2.0 Hub
          vendor: Standard Microsystems Corp.
          physical id: 1
          bus info: usb@1:1
          version: b.b3
          capabilities: usb-2.00
          configuration: driver=hub maxpower=2mA slots=4 speed=480Mbit/s
        *-usb:0
             description: USB hub
             product: USB 2.0 Hub
             vendor: Standard Microsystems Corp.
             physical id: 1
             bus info: usb@1:1.1
             version: b.b3
             capabilities: usb-2.00
             configuration: driver=hub maxpower=2mA slots=3 speed=480Mbit/s
           *-usb
                description: Generic USB device
                vendor: Standard Microsystems Corp.
                physical id: 1
                bus info: usb@1:1.1.1
                version: 3.00
                capabilities: usb-2.10
                configuration: driver=lan78xx maxpower=2mA speed=480Mbit/s
        *-usb:1
             description: Keyboard
             product: USB Receiver
             vendor: Logitech
             physical id: 2
             bus info: usb@1:1.2
             version: 29.01
             capabilities: usb-2.00
             configuration: driver=usbhid maxpower=98mA speed=12Mbit/s
        *-usb:2
             description: Keyboard
             product: 2.4G Keyboard Mouse
             vendor: MOSART Semi.
             physical id: 3
             bus info: usb@1:1.3
             version: 81.13
             capabilities: usb-1.10
             configuration: driver=usbhid maxpower=100mA speed=12Mbit/s
  *-network:0 DISABLED
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 2
       logical name: wlan0
       serial: b8:27:eb:13:71:c5
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=brcmfmac driverversion=7.45.18 firmware=01-6a2c8ad4 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
  *-network:1
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 3
       logical name: eth0
       serial: b8:27:eb:46:24:90
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=lan78xx driverversion=1.0.6 duplex=full ip=10.0.0.92 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
```

### EDIT: I am using a snap to create the Access Point

I am now using [the wifi-ap snap](https://docs.ubuntu.com/core/en/stacks/network/wifi-ap/docs/reference/configuration) in order to create a wifi network. This works fine, however, I do not know how I can configure it the way I want it to (mentioned above).

Thanks for the help!

Comment: There is a [snap](https://docs.ubuntu.com/core/en/stacks/network/wifi-ap/docs/) for that.

Comment: @Jos thanks for your comment. I have now managed to get my Access Point up and running - however, I can't configure the access point so that it does not grant internet access. Do you know what configuration variable I have to change so that it does not allow internet access if your're in the wifi? Thanks for your help!

Comment: I would use two `iptables` rules for that. Packets coming in to the wlan0 interface should be dropped if their destination is anything but 192.168.*. On the other hand, packets coming in on the eth0 side destined for anything but the server itself should be dropped.

Comment: @jos Those are not comments!  *They're answers!*  Please post one and I'll come back and upvote...

Comment: @Fabby well, allright. I don't use the snap I mentioned, I have no idea if it will run on a Raspberry Pi, and the `iptables` question ought to be a different post, but hey.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [snap](https://docs.ubuntu.com/core/en/stacks/network/wifi-ap/docs/) to do exactly that.

I don't know if the Access Point package can be configured to prevent your network clients from accessing the network. However, you can always create two `iptables` rules for that:

1. a rule to drop packets coming in from the internet with destination other than the server IP;
2. a rule to drop packets coming from the LAN destined for the internet, in other words, with a destination other than 192.168.*.

Comment: As promised! **:-)**